# Char string length not getting initialized properly despite literally putting in the integer size I want it to be?

Tags: c, variable-assignment

I'm working with char arrays in C. I'm setting the size in a previous step. When I print it out it clearly shows the num_digits as 1. 
But then when I put it in to set the size of a char array to make it a char array of size num_digits, its setting the size of the array as 6. 
In the next step when I print strlen(number_array), it prints 6. Printing it out I get something with a lot of question marks. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
int num_digits = get_num_digits(number);
printf("Num digits are %d\n", num_digits);
char number_array[num_digits];
printf("String len of array: %d\n", strlen(number_array));
```

Comment: As far as I know, this technically isn't valid C because the standard doesn't allow variable-length arrays (yet?), but some compilers still provide this as an extension to the language, but you shouldn't rely on it because a different compiler may strictly comply to the standard and thus reject your code

Comment: Variable sized arrays are supported from C99 on.

Comment: @ForceBru the compiler would reject it during compilation and not produce an exectuable, yet here there clearly is. VLA's became standard in C99 but optional in C11.

Comment: The array (and in fact every local variable in a C program) needs to be initialized before it's used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to null terminate your array.

```c
char number_array[num_digits + 1];
number_array[num_digits] = '\0';
```

Without this null terminator, C has no way of know when you've reached the end of the array.

Comment: You also need to initialize the other bytes in the array. Otherwise, any one of them could be a `'\0'`, and `strlen` won't report the expected length.

Comment: Ideally `number_array[0] = '\0';` since there is no other data set in the string.

Answer (score 0):

just use 'sizeof' instead of 'strlen'

printf("String len of array: %d\n", sizeof(number_array));

Comment: Are you sure this answers the question? OP knows what size it is - because it was defined to be that size.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple possible issues I see here:

- As noted in [Michael Bianconi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57484136/197011), C character arrays (often called strings) require null terminators. You would explicitly set this this with something like:

  `number_array[number + 1] = '\0';   /* See below for why number + 1 */`

Rather than just setting the last element to null, pre-initializing the entire character array to nulls might be helpful. Some compilers may do this for you, but if not you'll need to do this explicitly with something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_digits + 1; i ++) number_array[i] = '\0';
```

Note that with gcc I had to use C99 mode using `-std=c99` to get this to compile, as the compiler didn't like the initialization within the for statement.

- Also, the code presented sets the length of the character array to be the same length as `number`'s length. We don't know what get_num_digits returns, but if it returns the actual number of significant digits in an integer, this will come up one short (see above and other answer), as you need an extra character for the null terminator. An example: if the number is 123456 and get_number_digits returns 6, you would would need to set the length of number_array to 7, instead of 6 (i.e. `number + 1`).

Answer (score 0):

`char number_array[num_digits];` allocates some space for a string. It's an array of `num_digits` characters. Strings in C are represented as an array of characters, with a null byte at the end. (A null byte has the value zero, not to be confused with the digit character `'0'`.) So this array has room for a string of up to `num_digits - 1` characters.

`sizeof(number_array)` gives you the array storage size. That's the total amount of space you have for a string plus its null terminator. At any given time, the array can contain a string of any length up to `number_array - 1`, or it might not contain a string at all if the array doesn't contain a null terminator.

`strlen(number_array)` gives you the length of the string contained in the array. If the array doesn't contain a null terminator, this call may return a garbage value or crash your program (or make demons fly out of your nose, but most computers fortunately lack the requisite hardware).

Since you haven't initialized `number_array`, it contains whatever happened to be there in memory before. Depending on how your system works, this may or may not vary from one execution of the program to the next, and this certainly does vary depending on what the program has been doing and on the compiler and operating system.

What you need to do is:

- Give the array enough room for the null terminator.
- Initialize the array to an empty string by making setting the first character to zero.
- Optionally, initialize the whole array to zero. This is not necessary, but it may simplify further work with the array.
- Use `%zu` rather than `%d` to print a size. `%d` is for an `int`, but `sizeof` and `strlen` return a `size_t`, which depending on your system may or may not be the same size of integers.

```
char number_array[num_digits + 1];
number_array[0] = 0;  // or memset(number_array, 0, sizeof(number_array));
printf("Storage size of array: %zu\n", sizeof(number_array));
printf("The array contains an empty string: length=%zu\n", strlen(number_array));
```